# Jquery get from mysql works only first time

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following jquery script

```
$("li").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    $.get("getData.php", {id: id}, function(data){
        $("ul").after(data);
    });
    $(this).css("color","red");
});
```

and the getData.php file

```
<?php
          include("db_config.php");
          $ctgID = $_GET["id"];
          if(isset($ctgID))
          {
            getData($dbh, $ctgID);
          }

          function getData($dbh, $ctgID)
          {

           try{
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = $dbh->prepare("select ctgid, ctgdescription from categories where ctgparentid = $ctgID");
            $sql->execute();
            $result = $sql->rowCount();
            if($result >0)
            {
                echo "<ul>";
                while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT))
                {
                    echo "<li class=\"subCtg\" id=\"". $row[0] . "\">" . $row[1] . "</li>";
                }
                echo "</ul>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "1";
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e);
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Even if the above is working perfectly for the top level categories its not working when i am clicking on the subCtg class that is created. Can you help me please?

Comment: unrelated to the problem (thus the comment), but shouldn't you use bindValue() on $ctgID in a PDO prepared statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use click event like this, that trigger on your existing and dynamic lists as well:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'ul li', function(){
    .....
});
```

### Take a look on this example

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', 'li', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $(this).parent('ul').after('<ul><li>new item click here </li></ul>');
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/YdByT/

Comment: Still executed one time

Comment: @Antegeia is there any class or id before parent ul?

Comment: Nop, parent url is at localhost/rv, i am running the script at this url

Comment: @Antegeia take a look how you can apply it.

Answer (score 0):

Use  Jquery Bind instead of click event ..

```
$( ".subCtg" ).bind( "click", function() {
  alert( "User clicked " );
});
```

[Jquery Bind](https://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Comment: Try after bind class Name - "subCtg" instead of LI tag

Answer (score 0):

As you load new ul/li elements, you have to bind the "click"
event on them.

Try this:

PHP

```
...
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT))
    {
        echo "<li class=\"subCtg\" onclick=\"myFunc(".$row[0].");\" id=\"". $row[0] . "\">" . $row[1] . "</li>";
    }
...
```

Javascript

```
$("li").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    myfunc(id);
});

function myFunc(id){
    $.get("getData.php", {id: id}, function(data){
        $("#"+id).parent(ul).after(data);
    });
    $("#"+id).css("color","red");
}
```

An only-javascript approach could be:

```
function myFunc(id){
    $.get("getData.php", {id: id}, function(data){
        $("#"+id).parent(ul).after(data);
    });
    $("#"+id).css("color","red");
    //create onclick event on new elements
    $("li").each(function(){
        $(this).click(myFunc($(this).attr("id")));
    });
}
```